# How to convert data in unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Now I have data like this `"1234567890"`, first it is `System.Object`
I want convert it to `long`.
I tried like this
`(long) data`
`data as long`
`data as System.Int64`

It seems they all not work,anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First got your object as string if needed:

```
string mystringnumber = mysystemobject as String;
```

You can use this:

```
long.parse(mystringnumber);
```

or:

```
if (long.TryParse(mystringnumber,null))
{
dosomething();
}
```